# What is the default date format for access input?

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2003

I am not really experienced with `ms-access db`. I have the following sql-code that ask for input from the user:

```
SELECT c.the_date, E.[iD #] AS ID, E.[first name] AS fname
      FROM [date-table] AS c, employeetbl AS E
WHERE c.the_date between [enter a beginning date] and [Enter an end date];
```

- What format should the input date from the user be? (`mm-dd-yyyy` or `dd-mm-yyyy`)
- Is `mm-dd-yyyy` format for date type in ms access by default?
- Can I also determine the default format? or can I somehow change this
  using    either access vba or sql.
- I also want to keep looping until the user inputs the right date
  format. Is this possible in vba?

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Since access is desktop software, I suspect it is whatever the regional settings for the computer are set to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `Format` to ensure the date is entered in the correct format to the table: i.e `Format (Date, "yyyy-mm-dd")`.
However, ensuring the user enters the correct format may be a little tricky, since '2015-03-09' may be March 9th or September 3rd. 
For the user to enter a date that can't be ambiguous I guess the best format is something like `dd-mmm-yyyy` (ie. `09-mar-2015` or `03-sep-2015`).